# How to add DateTime class support in php 5.1.6

Tags: php, datetime

I have php 5.1.6 and got below thing but still not able to enable class support

> Note: Experimental DateTime support in
>   PHP 5.1.x Although the DateTime class
>   (and related functions) are enabled by
>   default since PHP 5.2.0, > it is
>   possible to add experimental support
>   into PHP 5.1.x by using the following
>   flag before configure/compile:
>   CFLAGS=-DEXPERIMENTAL_DATE_SUPPORT=1

But I did not understand where to add above line. Should it be added in php.ini?

Please help.

Comment: since PHP 5.2 has already reached end of support, you should rather update to PHP 5.3 or switch to a hoster offering a more recent version.

Comment: @Gordon: Thanks for your suggestion I don't wanted to go for PHP higher version but seems like this option will make everything easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a shared server you will not be able to to so (you could talk to your hosting provider). If not, you will have re compile PHP and append the above flags to your `./configure` line of flags (before your `make` and `make install` processes).