# Can help me to get date helper for older PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add DateTime class support in php 5.1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114718/how-to-add-datetime-class-support-in-php-5-1-6)

I am developing my application in PHP 5.2.6 and it all works successfully,
but now after uploading to my main server that runs PHP 5.1.4, i have some bugs about date function ..

now i found *date_create* and *date_format* is missing as function in PHP 5.1.4.

Any one can help me or show me the way to make similar function manually?

```
<update status>
```

by now i use :

```
if ( ! function_exists('date_create'))
{
    function date_create($date)
    {
        return strtotime($date);
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists('date_format'))
{
    function date_format($date,$format)
    {
        return date($format, $date);
    }
}
```

do you think it's ok?

Comment: Those are the procedural aliases for methods of the DateTime class. That's quite a big dependency to replicate...

Answer (score 2):

PHP 5.1.4 is about 6 years old now, I would suggest that you update your PHP installation, or contact your host about migrating to have a newer version of PHP.

`date_create()` and `date_format()` depend on the DateTime class.  To reproduce functionality, there would be a significant amount of development required.

If you have the appropriate permissions you can recompile your version of PHP to enable the experimental DateTime class, but if you have those permissions, you most likely have the permissions to update.

There are two options that are no longer maintained that may be able to assist you.  The PEAR package https://github.com/pear/Date and the PECL package http://pecl.php.net/package/date_time